# peripeteia (usage)

Tags: single-word-requests

In addition to its typical usage, "sudden/unexpected reversal of
circumstances", can it also be used to mean, more or less,
"the moment when you suddenly realize that everything you know
is wrong"? If not, is there a word for that? Or a better word
for it than peripeteia?

Comment: Hello, John. Which dictionaries have you checked in to see if they give the suggested sense?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My Webster's 9th New Collegiate, which is the only hardcopy I have, plus various online google hits when I entered "peripeteia", but I didn't pay much attention to their pedigree. Anyway, nothing I found explicitly suggested the precise meaning I'm looking for. So I'm kind of just wondering if I'm wandering too far afield by using it this way. Or, even better, if there's an even better word for it.

Comment: One word commonly used for the realisation is *epiphany.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks, Andrew. But two things: (1)it doesn't quite carry the sense of "reversal" I'm looking for, and (2)epiphany suggests you've suddenly realized a truth, whereas I'm looking for a word suggesting that what you'd previously accepted as true, you suddenly realize is false (without necessarily realizing any alternative truth).

Comment: to have a eureka moment: a sudden realization about something.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks, Lambie. Also doesn't emphasize "reversal" quite as much as I'd like... Something you've believed without question all your life, and suddenly realize is completely wrong. I think maybe Andrew might come a little closer, maybe as the two-word "peripetic epiphany", or something along those lines, except that I'm not seeing any bona fide adjectival form for peripeteia.

Comment: You said it was not about the reversal per se.  You suddenly realize something is false, **you said**. :)

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, my bad.

Comment: It's good to (a) do and (b) give the results of (if only to prevent futile repetition by others)  research (linked and attributed) even if unhelpful. // 'Bombshell' probably improves on 'epiphany', as the unpleasant aspect is at least strongly connoted. But still broader than "the moment when you suddenly realize that everything you 'know' is wrong", and informallish.  A **paradigm shift** is more formal and is defined by [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paradigm-shift) as 'a time when the usual and accepted way of doing or thinking about something changes completely'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, thanks for the link (which I upvoted there)

Comment: Neither answer at the suggested "original" post help. Voting to reopen.